# How to read thread dump?

Tags: java, multithreading, websphere, dump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thread Dump Analysis Tool / Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156434/thread-dump-analysis-tool-method)

I have a java aplication deployed in WAS 7.0.0.15. I want to analyze that the application which i have deployed is having some threads in hung state or not. So i want to take thread dump of server with and without application deployed. I used wsadmin for taking dump but not able to interpret the dump file.

Can any one help here ? also, let me know other methods of taking thread dump.

Comment: Nto really. WAS runs on IBM JVM, which has a different format for dump files. You should use IBMs tools (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

I use the [IBM Support Assistant (ISA)](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/isa/), which is IBM:s tool. From it, you can download plugins for a bunch of different analysis activities. I use the plugin called "IBM Thread and Monitor Dump Analyzer for Java (TMDA)" for thread dump analysis.

Note: I'm using it for WAS 6.1 but AFAIK it should work for WAS 7 just as fine.

Comment: Correct. The ISA will support WAS 7 as well. [ISA Product List](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=3455&uid=swg27013117)