# PrimeFaces 3.5 Warning datatable has filtering enabled but no filteredValue model reference is defined. Is capable of freezing server?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an application already in production that is already working well, but sometimes when the users try to login the application doesn't let them log in and gets freezed, and that lasts for like 10 minutes, checking the logs all that I could find is this warning, which repeats it self for like 10 minutes, which the page is trying to load and then the server resets by it self. I was wondering if you know if this warning is so bad that it is capable of not letting the application work, or if the error might be in another place, this also only happens like twice a day so maybe it is server configuration error, we have PF 3.5, JSF 2.0, wildfly 12. Any advice is appreciated

```
019-08-02 09:55:25,233 WARNING [org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable] (default task-11) DataTable accordion:frmCaja:dtbFrmConsMvto has filtering enabled but no filteredValue model reference is defined, for backward compatibility falling back to page viewstate method to keep filteredValue. It is highly suggested to use filtering with a filteredValue model reference as viewstate method is deprecated and will be removed in future.
2019-08-02 09:55:25,505 WARNING [org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable] (default task-5) DataTable accordion:frmCaja:dtbFrmConsMvto has filtering enabled but no filteredValue model reference is defined, for backward compatibility falling back to page viewstate method to keep filteredValue. It is highly suggested to use filtering with a filteredValue model reference as viewstate method is deprecated and will be removed in future.
2019-08-02 09:55:25,588 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-13) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, primefaces.js, from library, primefaces.
2019-08-02 09:55:25,589 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-13) : java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:162)
    at io.undertow.conduits.BytesSentStreamSinkConduit.write(BytesSentStreamSinkConduit.java:70)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:646)
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.doWrite(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:164)
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:128)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:150)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:240)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2099)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:573)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:149)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:283)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:125)
    at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:99)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.MetricsHandler.handleRequest(MetricsHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.MetricsChainHandler.handleRequest(MetricsChainHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1526)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Of things seem stuck, threaddumps are your friend.

Comment: @Kukeltje what do you mean dude? of things? by the way this only happens in one of the companys that has the software, and also that warning of title doesn't appear in PF 7.0 that im migrating hehe, what is threaddumps?

Comment: @Kukeltje hmmm so you don't think the warning has anything to do with server freezing some times? just threads? but then if that is the problem what can I do to make the thread better?

Comment: you are effectively asking something like: _"If my car does not ride, what can I do to make it ride"_ Causes can vary from: no gas, broken engine, forgot to take the parking brake off, lost keys etc, to even road block, traffic jam, not allowed because no taxes paid etc... a thread dump helps to find causes of not 'riding'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277091

Comment: Causes are sometimes found in minutes... Solutions too sometimes, sometimes not. Not responding applications are very often caused by connectionpool starvation or deadlocks in code or memory issues (app going into Garbage collection). All things your colleages should be able to help with.

Comment: @Kukeltje Okay I trust you mate, im searching for now tools and methods for thread dump, but which one would you recommend?

Comment: start with the basic jdk ones... For initial investigation, good enough

Comment: This almost sounds like the good old issue with NTFS locking up files. Are you by any chance using Windows to deploy the application ?

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg I will confirm you that soon brother, in my machine im on linux, but maybe on the company machine to deploy its windows ill check about that

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg It is on a windows machine mate, but what is so bad about it? can you link me something to read about possible cause please :)

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast To explain - on Windows, processes can lock files in a way that means that for example a directory or file can't be removed, so you can get different kind of deployment issues caused by that until the operating system lets go of the file. On most UNIX/Linux filesystem it works differently, allowing you to remove files instantly, with locked files being moved into a an invisible temporary area that waits for processes to let the file go (allowing the process to still access it, even if it is "removed").

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast Hard to say for sure that's the cause here, but it definetly sounds related.

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg okay mate thank you, thats something that could be checked I will tell my partner that has that assignement, thank you :)